# How to set row's height in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm dynamically adding rows into my `TableLayoutPanel` but I just can't configure there height.

The code might look long, but it's a very simple one.

**An explanation about the code:**

The code creates a `TableLayoutPanel` and set it's properties. After that, the code creates `Pictureboxes` and `Labels` according to how many movies there are in the database. After creating a `Picturebox` and a `Label` the code puts both of them in a `Panel` and then the code inserts the `Panel` into the `TableLayoutPanel`. The problem is the row's height.

**The output:**

[image]

**Here is the code I'm using:**

```
 Dim movieN As Integer = MoviesDataSet.movies.Rows.Count
    Dim tablePanel As New TableLayoutPanel

    With tablePanel
        .Size = New Point(Me.ClientRectangle.Width - 10, Me.ClientRectangle.Bottom - 55)
        .ColumnCount = 4
        .GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows
        .AutoScroll = True
        .Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5, 50)
        .CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Inset
        .ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25.0!))
        .ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25.0!))
        .ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25.0!))
        .ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25.0!))
        .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Top
    End With


    For Each MovieRow As DataRow In MoviesDataSet.Tables("movies").Rows
        'define two new controls to be added
        Dim myLabel As New Label
        Dim myPicture As New PictureBox
        Dim container As New Panel

        'set the properties of the new controls
        myLabel.Text = MovieRow("movieName")
        myLabel.AutoSize = True
        myLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(30, 110)
        With myPicture
            .Image = Image.FromFile(MovieRow("moviePhoto"))
            .Tag = MovieRow("ID")
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(2, 2)
            .Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        End With

        'here we add the controls to a layout panel to
        'manage the positioning of the controls
        With container
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
            .Controls.Add(myPicture)
            .Controls.Add(myLabel)
        End With


        With tablePanel.Controls

            .Add(container)

        End With

        'here we add a handler for the picture boxs click event
        AddHandler myPicture.Click, AddressOf MyPictureClickEvent
    Next

    Me.Controls.Add(tablePanel)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the last row bothering you?

Comment: everything is bothering me. The first rows are not displaying the label, that's because there is not enough height given to the row, and I have no idea how to do that..
I would like to set **all** of the rows height to 180

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got an answer. In order to set the height of the row, all you have to do is is to add this:

```
tablePanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150))
```

you should add this line **after** adding the `Panel` into the `TableLayoutPanel`

A snippet:

```
        '.... THE CODE ABOVE CAN BE SEEN IN THE QUESTION POST
        With container
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            .Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0)
            .Controls.Add(myPicture)
            .Controls.Add(myLabel)
        End With


        With tablePanel.Controls

            .Add(container)

        End With
        tablePanel.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150))
        'here we add a handler for the picture boxs click event
        AddHandler myPicture.Click, AddressOf MyPictureClickEvent
    Next

    Me.Controls.Add(tablePanel)
End Sub
```

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 10):

Try This :

```
For Each RS As RowStyle In tablePanel.RowStyles    
     RS.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute         
     RS.Height = 180    
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have found the solution!